# Como faço para saber endereço de cada posição do vetor em C?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Estou a ter problema em saber endereço do vetor e endereço de cada posição do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int vec[]={52,13,12,14};

printf("Endereço de vetor %d",&vec);
printf("vec[0]%d,vec[1]%d,vec[2]%d,vec[3]%d\n", &vec[0],&vec[1],&vec[2],&vec[3]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se quiser apresentar o endereço que um ponteiro está referindo, use `%p` no lugar de `%d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pegar o endereço do vetor basta usar a própria variável dele. A questão é que o *placeholder* de [formatação do `printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) correto é o `%p` para receber um ponteiro. Isso vai exigir um *cast* `(void *)` (ponteiro genérico) para encaixar corretamente (pelo menos em compiladores com opções mais seguras de codificação).

O mesmo vale para os valores do elementos. Mas aí vai usar o operador `&` já que o normal é pegar os valores deles.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int vec[] = {52, 13, 12, 14};
    printf("Endereço de vetor %p\n", (void*)vec);
    printf("vec[0] = %p, vec[1] = %p, vec[2] = %p, vec[3] = %p\n", (void*)&vec[0], (void*)&vec[1], (void*)&vec[2], (void*)&vec[3]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9Ap79L). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/easwnyfa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Address.c).

Comment: E como faço para saber o endereço do vetor em hexadecimal ?

Comment: Ele está mostrando em hexadecimal